# Green Lantern who can make constructs almost instantly

Tags: dc, comics, character-identification, green-lantern, blackest-night

I'm looking for a member of the Green Lantern Corps, somewhere during the *Blackest Night* run.  I've looked through all the members listed [here](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Corps), but no luck.

He was not widely used, but he was mentioned as making constructs crazy fast.  I think he was noted as being some kind of general as well.

They were not human, but I do believe they were humanoid.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're looking for [General Kreon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreon) as he was re-introduced during *Green Lantern* #12 (2006) as one of the "Lost Lanterns" that Hal Jordan killed when he was Parallax. Not part of the Blackest Night arc, but very shortly before.

> General Kreon is one of the greatest and most decisive war leaders in the universe. You never see a beam from his ring. The construct is just *on* or *off*. His mind's *that* fast.

[image: Kreon described as making constructs very fast]

Answer (score 15):

You are talking about [Kreon of Tebis](https://greenlantern.fandom.com/wiki/Kreon), Green Lantern of Sector 2002. (DC Database entry [here](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Kreon_(New_Earth)).)

[image: Kreon]

Kreon was one of the "temporary" Green Lanterns recruited by Hal Jordan before he went crazy and killed anyone in his way to Oa during Emerald Twilight.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreon) says "At one point, he was described as one of the greatest and most decisive **war leaders** in the universe. His signature trait as a Green Lantern was that his ring never showed a beam; **his constructs were simply 'on' and 'off'**, suggesting that his mind apparently moved quite fast."

Kreon was depowered by Hal Jordan, then taken by the Manhunters to Biot to power a series of stolen power rings.  Kreon died when Hal Jordan attempted to revive and rescue the Lost Lanterns months or years later.